# ng-grid height is incorrect (due to unnecessay scroll bars) when using footer template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am using angular with [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/#/examples) and I want the height of my grid to adjust according to number of rows.

Here's what I did when there was no footer:

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" ng-style="getTableStyle()"></div>
```

+

```
$scope.getTableStyle = function() {
    var rowHeight     =  30;
    var headerHeight  =  35;
    return {
        height: ($scope.selectedTab.materials.length * rowHeight + headerHeight) + "px"
    };
};
```

And that went OK.

But when I added a footer with template:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'tab.materials',
    rowHeight: 30,
    headerRowHeight: 35,
    footerRowHeight: 35,
    showFooter: true,
    footerTemplate: '<div ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" style="width:{{col.width}}px; display: inline-block"><div class="ngCellText">{{getTabSummary(selectedTab, col.field)}}</div></div>',
```

and changed `getTableStyle` to this:

```
$scope.getTableStyle= function() {
    var rowHeight     =  30;
    var headerHeight  =  35;
    var footerHeight  =  35;
    return {
        height: ($scope.selectedTab.materials.length * rowHeight + headerHeight + footerHeight + 5) + "px"
    };
};
```

The grid now appears with a vertical scroll bar (and as consequence -> with a horizontal as well).

See plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/jZJLidotNoQR3lKppI2p?p=preview

Comment: Nothing appears in your plunker. Just an empty select box. Plz fix it cause i'm too lazy to repair it. Then I will look again.

Comment: everything works for me in chrome

Comment: Sorry, nothing but an empty select on Chrome 35.0.1916.153 m, FF 30.0 or IE 11. Doesn't display anything on my elderly Opera.

Comment: Oh, yes. Seems like ui-github is currently not reachable for me. I'll check later.

Comment: Change that line to `height: ($scope.selectedTab.materials.length * rowHeight + headerHeight + footerHeight + 10) + "px"`